# iOS アプリで画面の向きを固定する方法を教えていただけませんか？

Tags: ios, monaca

調べた結果、 Xcode で iOS アプリの画面の向きを固定できそうなことは分かりました。

[Monaca](https://ja.monaca.io/) を使って開発しているため、 [Monaca](https://ja.monaca.io/) で画面の向きを固定する方法を知りたいです。

どなたか教えていただけないでしょうか？  
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

uiファイルの記述はDeprecatedとなっており、現在のプロジェクトでは利用できません。
代わりに、下記のページ記載の通り、Info.plistファイルを修正してUISupportedInterfaceOrientationsを指定してください。

http://docs.monaca.mobi/cur/ja/reference/config/ios_configuration/

Comment: ありがとうございます！解決しました！

Answer (score 1):

[リファレンス](http://docs.monaca.mobi/2.9/en/reference/native/screen_orientation/)を見る限りは`.ui`ファイルにスタイルを設定すれば固定できるように見えます。

```
{
  "top" : { ... },
  "bottom" : { ... },
  "style": {
      // ここに固定したい向きだけを指定する。
      "screenOrientation": "landscape"
  }
}
```

monacaを使用したことが無いため間違っているかもしれません。

Comment: ありがとうございます！調べてみます！

Answer (score 1):

MonacaApp-Info.plistというファイルがMonaca IDEを開くとiosディレクトリの下にあるはずです。

[image: MonacaApp-Info.plist]

そのファイルを開き、「UISupportedInterfaceOrientations」というKeyのvalueを編集します。これはアプリがサポートする画面の向きを管理するパラメーターです。例えば、アプリで許可する方向として「UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait」のみを残した場合はアプリは縦固定となります。

[image: MonacaApp-Info.plist:Edit]